# Helping users avoiding to retype login and password again

Tags: web-part, mysite

I wanted to know if there is some way that I could prevent users inform their login and password again. I created a webpart for searching people from website and bring some some information in my results. Among these information, I bring my site's path and the picture from every user profile.
The problem is when the information renders at the page and then the user is prompted to provide its login and password again. I guess this thing is happening because I am bringing up the user's address from my sites and his picture which is actually the picture's address

As these information comes from another site, the page that returns the results prompts user's login and password and if he don't, the pictures doesn't show up in the results.

Is there some configuration that I must do so the user does not have to provide his login and password?

Comment: Where are the pictures? It should not ask for credentials if the pictures are stored on the same domain

Comment: And in fact they are in the same domain but now when the page reloads with the results, it asks the user to type in a login and password and just to show user's pictures. If the user does not type any credentials he does not see the pictures.

Comment: try adding the URL where the pictures are stored as a trusted site and see if it only asks for the password once...

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand very well what you asked me to do. How can I put the picture's url as trusted site? I was thinking if Sharepoint does have some configuration, perhaps in Central Administration that I could disable this thing so that it won't ask again for login and password even knowing that these users are already logged in.

This environment is installed in our client and we are working with Sharepoint Premise. The authentication was configured to work with AD.

Comment: I hadn't seen your reply. Have you solved this? It's more of a browser issue then a SharePoint issue. Any variation in the domain part of the URL will need to be authenticated. IE automatically sends the logged in user credentials when you are in an intranet zone.

Comment: Hi, we found the solution!

We had to make some changes at group policy to be applied to all network so the users that use the intranet without being prompted to provide their username and passwords again.